# Writing json file in node.js returns 'EROFS' error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a json file in node.js in the following way:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('./keywords.json', JSON.stringify(keywords), function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   else console.log("success");
});
```

However I get the following error:

**Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open './keywords.json'**

So, I tried to open the file before writing it, in the following way:

```
fs.open('./keywords.json', 'w', function (err, file) {
   if (err) throw err;
   fs.writeFile('./keywords.json', JSON.stringify(keywords), function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     else console.log("success");
   });
});
```

However the problem persists. How can i solve it? Thank you.

Comment: What is the environment where you are running this code?

Comment: Firebase cloud functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase provides only a read-only file system. You can not write files on the system. You would have to use some kind of an Object storage like Amazon S3 or [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).